# Getting secret in Power BI Power Query (M) from Azure Key Vault

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, azure-keyvault

Could you suggest how to get secret in Power BI Power Query (M) from Azure Key Vault, please?

I know that there are external 3d party beta-version connectors to Azure Key Vault but they are not signed, require decreasing security level (allow all unsigned content to be run on PowerBI service) what is not suitable from security prospective, need complex deployment (installing an on-premises data gateway), need special mapping for external connector and so on.

Azure Key Vault has REST API and idea to get secret via this API.
Access to Azure Key Vault for Power BI service and my AAD user is configured (Key Vault Crypto User, Key Vault Reader, Key Vault Secrets User).

I am trying to use next M-query in Power BI Desktop in queries Advanced editor (it is 1st step of course just to show the issue):

```
let
        Source = Json.Document(
            Web.Contents("https://<key vault name>.vault.azure.net/secrets/?api-version=7.4"),
            65001 // Unicode (UTF-8).
         )[value]
in
        Source
```

It requires authorization in Power BI Desktop (it's ok), I am selecting Organizational Account and use my AAD user. But if fails to authorize
[issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvRmQ.png)

There are couple of similar questions in web (like [stackoverflow 68355392](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68355392/power-bi-and-azure-key-vault)) but there is no answers on them.